# Revertible Dimension Reduction for Many Dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

Is there a list of dimension reduction techniques which are **revertible** (I can go back and forth between sub manifold and original space) and scale well to large (>1million dimensions)? The vector is very sparse. Ideally I could find a rough subspace of interest on a small number of examples (reduce to ~10k dimensions), and then train something like an autoencoder on the subspace for fine control.

- Going straight for an auto-encoders is probably out of the picture as a FC layers with >1M input size becomes very difficult memory wise.
- PCA is an option, but has a huge memory footprint.
- Random Projection doesn't seem to have a way to revert back to the original space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two candidates from [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.decomposition) (there might be more):

- [Incremental PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA): batch-like
- [Truncated SVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html#sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD): sparse

There are more supporting `inverse_transform`, but i took only the ones supporting sparse-input or working on batches.

Keeping 10k dimensions sounds very memory-intensive though, even when using sparse-input.